# Localization of accesskeys in internet explorer

Tags: html, localization, internet-explorer

We have an enterprise web application that we are converting from english to Thai. One area that has got us stumped is on the issue of "access keys". We use the "Accesskey" attribute in IE to provide short cuts to our buttons. However, how do we do this in Thai? Does HTML and IE support unicode access keys and if so how?

Our application is IE specific, so any specific technology that IE uses is welcome.

Comment: Ok, actually got this working. Apparently, IE does support unicode accesskeys and hence a unicode number can be put for the access key

Answer (score 0):

As you stated in your comment:

IE supports the use of a Unicode number in "accesskey" which is compatible with a wide range of regions internationally.